# sqlalchemy filter by json field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have model with `json column`. Example of model and data:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://...'

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
app.app_context().push()

class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, primary_key=True, )
    json_field = db.Column(db.JSON())

db.create_all()
db.session.add(Example(json_field={'id': None}))
db.session.add(Example(json_field={'id': 1}))
db.session.add(Example(json_field={'id': 50}))
db.session.add(Example(json_field={}))
db.session.commit()
```

Now I try to find records where `id == 1`:

```
query = db.session.query(Example).filter(Example.json_field['id'] == 1)
print(query.all())
```

And I getting the next error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator
>   does not exist: json = integer LINE 3: WHERE (example.json_field ->
>   'id') = 1

**The reason.** Look at generated query:

```
SELECT example.id AS example_id, example.json_field AS example_json_field 
FROM example 
WHERE (example.json_field -> %(json_field_1)s) = %(param_1)s
```

But in my case correct query should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE CAST(json_field->>'id' AS INTEGER) = 1;
```

**How can I do this?**

I have tried use [cast](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast), but unsuccessfully:

```
print(
    db.session.query(Example).filter(
        cast(Example.json_field['id'], Integer) == 1
    ).all()
)
```

The error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) cannot
>   cast type json to integer LINE 3: WHERE CAST((example.json_field ->
>   'id') AS INTEGER) = 1

As you can see `where clause` still wrong. Also I need to use range (`>`, `<=` etc.) conditions. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy's `SQLAlchemy` object – commonly named `db` – [gives access](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#road-to-enlightenment) to functions etc. from `sqlalchemy` and `sqlalchemy.orm`, and so `db.JSON` is the [generic `JSON` type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) that does not provide the Postgresql specific operators. You should instead use [`sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, primary_key=True, )
    json_field = db.Column(JSON)
```

With the proper type in place you must explicitly convert the [JSON to text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON.Comparator.astext) first and then cast to an integer:

```
db.session.query(Example).\
    filter(Example.json_field['id'].astext.cast(Integer) == 1)
```

This produces the desired predicate

```
CAST(json_field->>'id' AS INTEGER) = 1
```

The same applies to all types that cannot be directly cast from `json`. SQLAlchemy used to offer a shortcut for the combination of `astext` and `cast()`, but it has been removed in version 1.1 and above:

> Changed in version 1.1: The `ColumnElement.cast()` operator on `JSON` objects now requires that the `JSON.Comparator.astext` modifier be called explicitly, if the cast works only from a textual string.

Comment: hmmm this gives me `NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression`

Comment: Are you using `from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON`, or `sqlalchemy.types.JSON`? Also, SQLA 2, or 1.x? There's not much to go by with that error alone, so consider opening a question with a minimal verifiable example.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use raw sql in filter

```
from sqlalchemy import text

db.session.query(Example).filter(text("CAST(json_field->>'id' AS INTEGER) = 1")
```

Comment: less secure, if using parameters and not ORM friendly style :-)

Answer (score 3):

if you only use `filter(json_obj["key"] ... )` it will convert to sql like 
`model_name.json_obj -> 'key'`, which is still a json object,

if you use `filter(json_obj["key"].astext ...)`, the sql will be 
`model_name.json_obj ->> 'key'`, the result is a string object.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can use this expression:

```
db.session.query(Example).filter(
    Example.json_field.op("->>")("id").cast(Integer) == 1
)
```